# Read the text contents of a binary file and display it to stdout

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct filedata
{
        char data[100];
}data_t;

data_t * fname=NULL;

//IS AN ARRAY OF the structure filedata REQUIRED HERE

void quit()
{
      printf("\nPress enter to exit");
      fflush(stdin);
          getchar(); 
}    


int main()
{
char ch;   
    fname=(data_t *)malloc(sizeof(data_t));

    FILE *fptr=NULL;
    atexit(quit);
    printf("Please enter the file name to read : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",fname->data);    
    fptr=fopen(fname->data,"rb");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
            perror("Could not open the file ");
            return;
    }
    printf("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    printf("Contents of the file %s are : ",fname->data);

    while(fread(&fname, sizeof(data_t), 1,fptr) == 1)
    {
      // what do I put here? 
    }

    fclose(fptr);       
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read any binary file containing some text or numbers in it on my computer and display it on the stdout.

How do I do it?

Shall I declare an array of the structure file data like `data_t data[100]`?

What should I put in the while loop above to display the contents?

**An example:** of course if I know the attributes inside the stucture like name,age etc then I can do something like

```
while ( fread ( &e, sizeof ( e ), 1, fp ) == 1 )
printf ( "\n%s %d %f", e.name, e.age, e.bs ) ;
```

But how do I read any text contents of any binary file and display it to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

The standard `strings(1)` utility will print 'printable characters'; by default, it only shows runs of four-or-more printable characters terminated by an unprintable character. This is a good enough definition, and `strings(1)` makes it easy to use the `-n` parameter to show longer or shorter strings.

I can think of two mechanisms to implement the utility: one would allocate an array `min` chars in length, and thus could be used for reading from pipes; the other wouldn't allocate an array, but could only work on files. Since the array version is more useful, I'll describe it.

You set up a standard loop:

```
int c;
int index = 0;
char arr[MAX];
FILE* f=fopen(whatever);

while((c=fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    int flush_output = 0;

    if(isgraph(c))
        arr[index++]=c;
    else if(c == ' ' && index > 0)
        arr[index++]=c;
    else if(index > min)
        flush_output = 1;

    if(flush_output || index == (sizeof(arr)-2)) {
        arr[index]='\0';
        printf("%s", arr);
        index=0;
    }
}
```

There's some unfortunate code near the end; but we cannot write past the end of the array, and we should only print out the output *before* the end of the array if we also had more than `min` characters collected so far. This beats duplicating the code, but there might be a cleaner mechanism than this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide on a representation. You could read out the file as 8 bit "chunks" and then the value as an 8 bit integer. Would that work for you?

If you want to see an example of a program that does things similar to what you want, you should check out `od(1)`. It dumps file contents in various format.

Comment: still I am not able to get  it, is there any other way around and will this line work for binary files while((c=fgetc(f)) != EOF)  STILL HAVING PROBLEM HELP ????????

Comment: I got a reply for my question from a person named jim and he says :    * In order to read a binary file you must know how the file was written. You must know how the variables were written, their size, in bytes. Their type, double, float, int, char, user defined type, etc. The order these variables were written to the file. And last the number of bytes required to hold each variable.

So it is usually not possible to take "any" binary file and read the contents. You may read a select binary file that you know the exact layout, but not a binary file that you do not know the layout.**

Jim